# how to deal with NA in neural network prediction result in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, r-caret

I'm applying neuralnet on titanic dataset (containing PClass, sex, Age, Sibsp, Parch, Fare, Embarked)

```
library(caret)
model_nnet <- train(as.factor(Survived) ~.,  
              method="nnet",
              train_df, 
              linout=FALSE, 
              trace = FALSE,
              preProcess = c("center", "scale"))

nnet_predict <- predict(model_nnet, test_df)
```

While I expected nnet_predict to be same length as testing dataframe (418 records), it actually contains NA and only have 331 results. Any advice on how to deal with it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for

```
summary(test_df)
```

You can see that there are missing values in `Age` & `Fare` column so before running `predict()` function you need to fix `NA` in these two columns.

One option could be to -

- Fill `NA` in `Fare` column with it's mean value.
- Fill `NA` in `Age` column with it's mean value wrt `Pclass` i.e.

---

```
if Pclass==1 then missing_age <- 37
if Pclass==2 then missing_age <- 29
else missing_age <- 24
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! extremely helpful. one noobie question though: is it always necessary to impute and create dummy variable on training and testing separately, or is there a better way?

Comment: Usually you should first treat your data for missing value/ outliers etc and then split it into train/test data. If data is already split then treat it combinedly and then split it again before running your model.